# Saxon not thread safe when re-using a DOM template

Tags: java, saxon

I am trying out Saxon HE as a replacement for the built-in JAXP implementation, and I am running into all kinds of threading problems with it.

For performance reasons I cache templates as DOM documents and reuse them across threads like this

```
        TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Document template = getFromCache(...);
        Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(new DOMSource(template));
        transformer.transform(new DOMSource(document), streamResult);
```

I know that DOM is not guaranteed to be thread-safe, but the JAXP XSLT implementation is working perfectly while Saxon crashes completely. How can this be?

Is there a way to make it work but keep caching in place for performance?

The exception in Saxon occurs at various places, but most commonly at:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ParentNode.nodeListItem(ParentNode.java:786) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.ParentNode.item(ParentNode.java:800) ~[na:1.7.0_71]
at net.sf.saxon.dom.DOMSender.walkNode(DOMSender.java:154) ~[Saxon-HE-9.6.0-7.jar:na]
at net.sf.saxon.dom.DOMSender.outputElement(DOMSender.java:243) ~[Saxon-HE-9.6.0-7.jar:na]
at net.sf.saxon.dom.DOMSender.walkNode(DOMSender.java:162) ~[Saxon-HE-9.6.0-7.jar:na]
at net.sf.saxon.dom.DOMSender.outputElement(DOMSender.java:243) ~[Saxon-HE-9.6.0-7.jar:na]
at net.sf.saxon.dom.DOMSender.walkNode(DOMSender.java:162) ~[Saxon-HE-9.6.0-7.jar:na]
at net.sf.saxon.dom.DOMSender.outputElement(DOMSender.java:243) ~[Saxon-HE-9.6.0-7.jar:na]
at net.sf.saxon.dom.DOMSender.walkNode(DOMSender.java:162) ~[Saxon-HE-9.6.0-7.jar:na]
at net.sf.saxon.dom.DOMSender.outputElement(DOMSender.java:243) ~[Saxon-HE-9.6.0-7.jar:na]
at net.sf.saxon.dom.DOMSender.walkNode(DOMSender.java:162) ~[Saxon-HE-9.6.0-7.jar:na]
at net.sf.saxon.dom.DOMSender.outputElement(DOMSender.java:243) ~[Saxon-HE-9.6.0-7.jar:na]
at net.sf.saxon.dom.DOMSender.walkNode(DOMSender.java:162) ~[Saxon-HE-9.6.0-7.jar:na]
at net.sf.saxon.dom.DOMSender.send(DOMSender.java:92) ~[Saxon-HE-9.6.0-7.jar:na]
at net.sf.saxon.dom.DOMObjectModel.sendSource(DOMObjectModel.java:250) ~[Saxon-HE-9.6.0-7.jar:na]
at net.sf.saxon.event.Sender.send(Sender.java:221) ~[Saxon-HE-9.6.0-7.jar:na]
at net.sf.saxon.style.StylesheetModule.loadStylesheetModule(StylesheetModule.java:128) ~[Saxon-HE-9.6.0-7.jar:na]
at net.sf.saxon.style.Compilation.compilePackage(Compilation.java:131) ~[Saxon-HE-9.6.0-7.jar:na]
at net.sf.saxon.style.Compilation.compileSingletonPackage(Compilation.java:94) ~[Saxon-HE-9.6.0-7.jar:na]
at net.sf.saxon.s9api.XsltCompiler.compile(XsltCompiler.java:543) ~[Saxon-HE-9.6.0-7.jar:na]
at net.sf.saxon.jaxp.SaxonTransformerFactory.newTemplates(SaxonTransformerFactory.java:152) ~[Saxon-HE-9.6.0-7.jar:na]
at net.sf.saxon.jaxp.SaxonTransformerFactory.newTransformer(SaxonTransformerFactory.java:108) ~[Saxon-HE-9.6.0-7.jar:na]
```

Comment: Can you synchronize access to a specific `Document`? If a DOM isn't guaranteed to be thread-safe, you're starting off on a bad foot by using it in multi-threaded scenarios without protecting access to a single instance.

Comment: Your approach seems reasonable since the TransformerFactory implementation should only need to read the DOM to create the Transformer (except when it does not). What do you mean with *crashes completely*: is there any exception thrown?

Comment: Added the most frequently occurring exception details...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know what causes the error you describe but `javax.xml.transform` has the `Templates` class which is the official way to reuse stylesheets in a thread-safe way and avoid the overhead of creating and parsing them for every single transformation.

1. Make the cache store `Templates` instead of DOM documents for a template source, using `TransformerFactory.newTemplates(Source)`.
2. Call `Templates.newTransformer()` on a cached Templates object to obtain a Transformer for a single transformation.

This should even be faster than your current solution.

---

EDIT:

The NPE seems to originate from a line in Xerces which reads:

```
fNodeListCache.fChildIndex = i;
```

In my eyes this is a strong clue that the multi-threaded access to the DOM causes the error and not Saxon. Don't know why the default TransformerFactory survives this scenario.

Comment: I just ran it with 0,15 range parallelStream - works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

You say: "For performance reasons I cache templates as DOM documents and reuse them across threads". But that's not going to help performance at all. It only saves you the I/O and XML-parsing cost, which is a tiny part of the cost of compiling a stylesheet. You should cache the Templates object, which is the compiled representation of the stylesheet. Not only does this give much more effective caching, but it also happens to be thread-safe.

Perhaps the built-in JAXP implementation compensates for the lack of thread-safety in the DOM by doing its own synchronization. It's certainly possible to do that, but this isn't a sensible use case so it hardly seems necessary.

You should also be aware that if you're concerned with performance, as you say you are, then supplying instance documents in DOM form is very inefficient with Saxon - it's typically 5-10 times slower than allowing Saxon to use its internal tree format.

Comment: I create complex input documents in Java using DOM API. Is there another API in Saxon to create XML documents on-the-fly and not cause a performance drop in Saxon? I've seen `TinyBuilder` but it's SAX-oriented and as such not very convenient for creating documents in the code...

Comment: All external tree models impose a penalty compared with Saxon's internal tree model; the internal model gets its performance boost *because* it severely constrains the ability to update the tree. If you need a mutable tree format that can also be used as input to Saxon (efficiently) I would recommend JDOM2 or XOM, which are much closer to the XDM data model than DOM is. Alternatively, it is sometimes more efficient to copy the DOM to a Saxon tree (e.g. using Configuration.buildDocument() on a DOMSource) prior to the transformation. Alternatively, just put up with the extra cost.